# Issue with POSTing JSON in a request to App Center API

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to use Notification Push method from App Center API from my application.

So I set a simple button on the screen which should POST a JSON file to an endpoint. 
Unfortunately, the button does not send a push notification to the device.

Also, trying to get a response from the server ends up as an error:

> System.Net.WebException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details.

Here's the code used when the button is clicked:

```cs
private void PushButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/username/appname/push/notifications");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json charset=UTF-8";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-API-Token", "apitokenhere");

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {

        string json = "{\"notification_content\":{\"name\":\"test\",\"title\": \"test\",\"body\": \"test :)\"}, \"notification_target\": null}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to start by catching the exception and seeing what the underlying error is

Comment: Ok, so I catched this exception: {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Could bad JSON cause the problem or I should look at the request headers?

Comment: it could be either